# Issues setting up Firebase SDK with Unity iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, unity-game-engine, appdelegate

I am a Unity game developer and know very little about app side code, so forgive me if I'm doing something stupid.

I'm trying to set up Firebase to work in my Unity iOS app. I'm in the very first setup, trying to get the SDK working.

So Firebase has you do a couple steps, and then they want you to do some initialization in your App Delegate. They want you to add two lines, an import and a configure. This is the code from their setup section.

```
@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}
```

So Unity doesn't actually use a traditional AppDelegate. I went sleuthing and found [this guy's work](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity%20custom%20app%20delegate&oq=unity%20custom%20app%20delegate&aqs=chrome..69i57.4566j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). He basically shows how to use a standard Unity Plugin to override the app delegate. So I put the following code in my Plugins folder.

```
#import "UnityAppController.h"
@import Firebase;

@interface OverrideAppDelegate : UnityAppController
@end


IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(OverrideAppDelegate)


@implementation OverrideAppDelegate


-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*) options
{
    NSLog(@"[OverrideAppDelegate application:%@ didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:%@]", application, options);
    [FIRApp configure];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:options];
}


@end
```

Now. I'm pretty sure the Plugin is working because I can find it in my XCode project, and when I was screwing around with it and had two instances of [FIRApp configure]; it actually crashed with an error basically saying, "don't configure twice". But Firebase has not received anything from my app. They have a little prompt that says, "Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app." I've uninstalled, reinstalled, tried their whole installation process again, and still nothing.

Any thoughts?? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What Firebase guide are you following? I'm pretty sure that plugin is for a native iOS app, not a Unity one. If you add the Firebase Plugin for Unity found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup you don't need to write any OS-specific code.

Comment: Okay let me give that a shot. Is there an easy way to see that it works, besides hook something up?

Comment: Add the Analytics plugin, it's easy to set up and you should see usage shortly after adding it. I've set this as the answer, but let me know if you run into any problems.
Edit: it notes that it might take up to 24 hours for data to included in reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing an app in Unity you can use the Firebase for Unity plugin rather than implementing your own iOS solution. Try adding Analytics to your app with [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start).